# Picking a camera to use with an Arduino uno. (Or freetronics eleven)

Tags: camera, arduino

Right, so after browsing my 'local' online computer shop with 'nary a basic idea of what I can to do I've decided I'd turn to people who knew more about electronics than me.

My plan is to hook a couple of motors and a basic camera to my Eleven (which apparently functions just like a Uno) and when the computer sends a command to the Eleven it snaps a picture and pipes it back to the PC.

My question to you fellows, is would that be possible, or do I have to add in more memory so it can buffer the image first? What camera should I use? I've seen multiple suggestions online and while I know the simplest solution would be to use a separate camera I'm looking for a more elegant and portable answer.

Answer (score 4):

Arduino is painfully slow to buffer raw image of any decent size, you would really want DMA & more memory to make it happen (i.e. ARM or FPGA).

But as you don't need any processing - there is a hope: 
There are cameras which have built-it JPEG compression.
So you just need to set it up according to your datasheet.

This way you can capture full-resolution images without having arduino's mind explode.

Here is an example of camera module I am talking about : 
http://www.aliexpress.com/snapshot/101347610.html (I've ordered this but it's not yet delivered)

Comment: Apologies for being a luddite here, but I honestly have next to no idea how those datasheets work. Am I correct in supposing I should be wiring the outputs to pins on my Eleven and then piping those inputs straight through to the computer with a sketch?

The camera module I was looking to use was http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10061 for reference, since the others output to analog which I don't want.

Thanks for the input so far!

Answer (score -1):

You can try ArduCAM shield to capture 1080p photo and save to SD card or transfer via serial port to PC. You can find more information from http://www.arducam.com